# HQL Count Query

Tags: hibernate, ejb, ejb-3.0, hql

I am trying to get a count from a table using HQL. Here's my code.

```
Long bgaCount = (Long)em.createQuery(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BiGlAccounts ").getSingleResult();
```

I know for a fact there are two records in the table but whenever I run this and check the value of `bgaCount` it returns 0. Do you see anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Is BiGlAccounts the name of your entity or the name of your table? Moving to NHib from SQL statements can cause adding the 's' at the end of the entity name. If the entity is called BiglAccount(without s) the you should change it. Nhib doesn't need the whatespaces at the end and the beginning, so I recommend you to remove them.
So I would try the following string for the first sight:
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BiGlAccount"

Comment: The entity is called BiGlAccounts. The corresponding table is BI_GL_ACCOUNTS. The white space doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the server needed to be cleaned. Once I cleaned and rebuilt it then it worked. I didn't change the code so don't ask me why but that fixed it.